# Use a unique constraint with pattern matching

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

My table has three fields which have to be unique when combined together for each row. My data altering cte will not enter a new row to that table based on said condition, but will continue entering rows to it's related table.

See following:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS e_tests(
  e_id BIGSERIAL,
  e_name VARCHAR(50),
  con VARCHAR(30),
  start_time TIMESTAMPTZ,
  PRIMARY KEY (e_id),
  UNIQUE (e_name, con, start_time)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS fdf_tests(
  b_id BIGSERIAL,
  e_ref BIGSERIAL,
  v VARCHAR(20),
  type VARCHAR(92),
  FOREIGN KEY (e_ref) REFERENCES e_tests(event_id),
  PRIMARY KEY (b_id)
);


CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE insert_on_conflict(input jsonb)
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $$
DECLARE
BEGIN
  WITH ins_e AS (
    INSERT INTO e_tests (e_name, start_time, con)
    SELECT inp->>'e_name' e_name, (inp->>'start_time')::timestamp start_time, inp->>'con' con
    FROM jsonb_array_elements(input) inp
    ON CONFLICT (e_name, start_time, con) DO UPDATE SET e_name=EXCLUDED.e_name
    RETURNING event_id, e_name
  ),
...Rest of procedure
```

This all works well but I need to use pattern matching for the e_name. So if we have a row where e_name is 'some string' and one of the new rows we want to insert has 'some str' in it with the same start_time and con we won't insert the new row.

So for example if the e_tests table is this:

```
e_id     e_name         con      start_time
--------------------------------------------------
1     'some string'     'ab'      some date
```

the following insert won't work:

```
INSERT INTO e_tests(e_name, con, start_time)
VALUES('some stri', 'ab', 'some date')
```

But this insert will work:

```
INSERT INTO e_tests(e_name, con, start_time)
VALUES('some stri', 'ab', 'some other date')
```

How do I achieve this?

** UPDATE **

The only way I can think of that doesn't use loops or inserting data through intermediate tables is perhaps with

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS e_tests(
  e_id BIGSERIAL,
  e_name VARCHAR(50),
  con VARCHAR(30),
  start_time TIMESTAMPTZ,
  PRIMARY KEY (e_id),
  --UNIQUE (e_name, con, start_time)
  EXCLUDE USING gist (e_name WITH =, start_time WITH =)
);
```

But I have no way to refer to the existing rows in an exclude or check constraint so...

Does it have to be inserting one by one with a for loop?? (So disappointing I thought postgres was magic)

Comment: One example isn't sufficient to define the behavior.  Do you want it based on the first 8 letters?  based on a LIKE (or ILIKE) operation between the column value and the new values with a '%' appended?

Comment: EXCLUDE constraints do not support DO UPDATE, only DO NOTHING.

Comment: I need to examine the following regex against the e_name column in the table: '%s.*?\-%s.*?\-%s' The problem is where to impalement it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This cannot be done in the conflict clause.  It only accepts index name or index columns as explained here: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/sql-insert.html

You should consider writing a "manual" check in your code.

Best regards,
Bjarni

Comment: I've tried exploring a manual check in the create table but I can't quite get it right. Can you give an example please?

Comment: I'm sorry for being unclear.  I meant that you have to do this in your code - in a loop for example.  This cannot be done with the insert on conflict method as far as I can see.

Comment: oh no inserting on by one with a for loop really? :(

Comment: Well - I don't see any other simple way at least.  Conflicts occur when contraints are broken and as far as I know, the contraints can only work on current row - not compare to other rows :-/